# Typescript: Autopopulate a property via getter/setter

Tags: typescript, getter-setter

I have a class for User Properties. I'm trying to auto-populate the 'fullname' property if firstName and lastName is updated. But so far, my code only populate it when it is updated manually by in the controller.

Is there a way to auto-update the 'fullname' without explicitly calling it?

```
export class UserDTO {
    id: number;
    fullname: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;

    private _fullname string;
    get fullname(): string {
        return this._fullname;
    }

    set fullname(value: string) {
        this._fullname = this.firstName + (this.lastName ? ' ' + this.lastName : '');
    } }
```

Usage in controller:

```
updatedUser.name = firstName + (lastName ? ' ' + lastName : '');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going about this all wrong. You don't need to set `fullName`.. and you certainly don't need a local variable for it.

```
export class UserDTO {
    id: number;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;

    get fullname(): string {
        return this.firstName + (this.lastName ? ' ' + this.lastName : '');
    }
}
```

When requesting fullname, it will always be up to date - and you cannot set it. You update it by setting `firstName` or `lastName`.